# WPF Multiple ViewModels and Multiple UserCotnrols

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

So I have a page that has a TabControl that uses multiple UserControls (each user control represents the contents of a TabItem).

I have a ComboBox in both user controls that share the same ItemsSource (`OrganizationSource`) and SelectedValue(`OrganizationSelected`) properties,

I however cannot seem to bind to ComboBox within the `EventDetails` UserControl, but it works flawlessly inside of the `OrganizationDetails` UserControl.

The `OutreachMVVM` is set to the DataContext for the parent page that the tabs reside in. I still have to set the datacontexts for the user controls themselves for it to work properly.

I just need to figure out how to set the binding for the ComboBox inside of the `EventDetails`. I saw something about dependency property but I do not understand it. I thought I would be able to set the binding for the ComboBox inside of `EventDetails` as the same for the ComboBox inside of `OrganizationDetails`, but that's not the case.

```
internal class OutreachMVVM : ViewModelBase
{
    public OutreachMVVM()
    {

        EventDetails = new EventDetailsVMB();   
        OrganizationDetails = new OrganizationDetailsVMB();
    }

    public EventDetailsVMB EventDetails { get; set; }
    public OrganizationDetailsVMB OrganizationDetails { get; set; }
}
```

**EventDetailsVMB:**

```
class EventDetailsVMB : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _eventTypeSelected;
    private string _zipSelected;

    private readonly UserListTableAdapter _userListTableAdapter = new UserListTableAdapter();
    private readonly EventTypeListTableAdapter _eventTypeListTableAdapter = new EventTypeListTableAdapter();
    private readonly CityListTableAdapter _cityListTableAdapter = new CityListTableAdapter();
    private readonly LocationInfoByZipTableAdapter _locationInfoByZipTableAdapter = new LocationInfoByZipTableAdapter();

    public string User { get; set; }
    public string EventName { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string County { get; set; }
    public string ServiceArea { get; set; }

    //Set EventType CombBox
    public ObservableCollection<string> EventTypeSource
    {
        get
        {
            var eventTypeList = _eventTypeListTableAdapter.GetEventTypeList();
            var eventTypeSource = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            eventTypeSource.AddRange(from DataRow row in eventTypeList.Rows select row.ItemArray[0].ToString());
            return eventTypeSource;
        }
    }

    //Set User ComboBox
    public ObservableCollection<string> UserSource
    {
        get
        {
            var userList = _userListTableAdapter.GetUserList();
            var userSource = new ObservableCollection<string>();

            foreach (var username in Enumerable.Where(userList, username => username.Username == Environment.UserName))
            {

                User = username.FullName;
            }

            userSource.AddRange(from DataRow row in userList.Rows select row.ItemArray[0].ToString());
            OnPropertyChanged("User");
            return userSource;
        }
    }

    //Set City RadAutoCompleteBox
    public ObservableCollection<string> CitySource
    {
        get
        {
            var cityList = _cityListTableAdapter.GetCityList();
            var citySource = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            citySource.AddRange(from DataRow row in cityList.Rows select row.ItemArray[0].ToString());
            return citySource;
        }
    } 


    public string EventTypeSelected
    {
        get { return _eventTypeSelected; }
        set
        {
            _eventTypeSelected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("EventTypeSelected");
        }
    }

    public string ZipSelected 
    { 
        get { return _zipSelected;  }
        set
        {
            _zipSelected = value;
            var locationInfo = _locationInfoByZipTableAdapter.GetLocationInfoByZip(_zipSelected);
            if (locationInfo.Rows.Count != 0)
            {
                City = locationInfo.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString();
                State = locationInfo.Rows[0].ItemArray[1].ToString();
                County = locationInfo.Rows[0].ItemArray[2].ToString();
                ServiceArea = locationInfo.Rows[0].ItemArray[3].ToString();
            }
            else if (ZipSelected.Length == 5) {}
            else
            {
                City = "";
                State = "TX";
                County = null;
                ServiceArea = null;
            }
            OnPropertyChanged("City");
            OnPropertyChanged("State");
            OnPropertyChanged("County");
            OnPropertyChanged("ServiceArea");
        } 
    }
}
```

**OrganizationDetailsVMB:**

```
class OrganizationDetailsVMB : ViewModelBase
{

    private string _organizationName;
    private string _street1;
    private string _street2;
    private string _city;
    private string _state;
    private string _zip;
    private string _county;
    private string _serviceArea;

    private bool _cbo;
    private bool _fbo;
    private bool _mo;
    private bool _sbo;
    private bool _sno;

    private readonly OrganizationListTableAdapter _organizationListTableAdapter = new OrganizationListTableAdapter();
    private readonly OrgByNameTableAdapter _orgByNameTableAdapter = new OrgByNameTableAdapter();
    private readonly OrgTypeByOrgNameTableAdapter _orgTypeByOrgNameTableAdapter = new OrgTypeByOrgNameTableAdapter();

    public string OrganizationSelected
    {
        get { return _organizationName; }
        set
        {
            _organizationName = value;
            var organizationQueryResults = _orgByNameTableAdapter.GetOrganizationByName(_organizationName);
            var orgTypeQueryResults = _orgTypeByOrgNameTableAdapter.GetOrgTypeByName(_organizationName);
            if (organizationQueryResults.Rows.Count != 0)
            {
                OrgStreet1Value = organizationQueryResults.Rows[0].ItemArray[1].ToString();
                OrgStreet2Value = organizationQueryResults.Rows[0].ItemArray[2].ToString();
                OrgCityValue = organizationQueryResults.Rows[0].ItemArray[3].ToString();
                OrgStateValue = organizationQueryResults.Rows[0].ItemArray[4].ToString();
                OrgZipValue = organizationQueryResults.Rows[0].ItemArray[5].ToString();
                OrgCountyValue = organizationQueryResults.Rows[0].ItemArray[6].ToString();
                OrgServiceAreaValue = organizationQueryResults.Rows[0].ItemArray[7].ToString();
                CBO = Convert.ToBoolean(orgTypeQueryResults.Rows[0].ItemArray[1]);
                FBO = Convert.ToBoolean(orgTypeQueryResults.Rows[0].ItemArray[2]);
                SBO = Convert.ToBoolean(orgTypeQueryResults.Rows[0].ItemArray[3]);
                MO = Convert.ToBoolean(orgTypeQueryResults.Rows[0].ItemArray[4]);
                SNO = Convert.ToBoolean(orgTypeQueryResults.Rows[0].ItemArray[5]);
            }
            else
            {
                OrgStreet1Value = "";
                OrgStreet2Value = "";
                OrgCityValue = "";
                OrgStateValue = "";
                OrgZipValue = "";
                OrgCountyValue = "";
                OrgServiceAreaValue = "";
                CBO = false;
                FBO = false;
                SBO = false;
                MO = false;
                SNO = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> OrganizationSource
    {
        get
        {
            var organizationList = _organizationListTableAdapter.GetOrganizationList();
            var organizationSource = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            organizationSource.AddRange(from DataRow row in organizationList.Rows select row.ItemArray[0].ToString());
            return organizationSource;
        }
    }

    public string OrgStreet1Value
    {
        get { return _street1; }
        set
        {
            if (_street1 != value)
            {
                Validator.ValidateProperty(value,
                    new ValidationContext(this, null, null) { MemberName = "OrgStreet1Value" });
                _street1 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("OrgStreet1Value");
            }
        }
    }

    public string OrgStreet2Value
    {
        get { return _street2; }
        set
        {
            if (_street2 != value)
            {
                Validator.ValidateProperty(value,
                    new ValidationContext(this, null, null) { MemberName = "OrgStreet2Value" });
                _street2 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("OrgStreet2Value");
            }
        }
    }

    public string OrgCityValue
    {
        get { return _city; }
        set
        {
            if (_street1 != value)
            {
                Validator.ValidateProperty(value,
                    new ValidationContext(this, null, null) { MemberName = "OrgCityValue" });
                _city = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("OrgCityValue");
            }
        }
    }

    public string OrgStateValue
    {
        get { return _state; }
        set
        {
            if (_state != value)
            {
                Validator.ValidateProperty(value,
                    new ValidationContext(this, null, null) { MemberName = "OrgStateValue" });
                _state = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("OrgStateValue");
            }
        }
    }

    public string OrgZipValue
    {
        get { return _zip; }
        set
        {
            if (_zip != value)
            {
                Validator.ValidateProperty(value,
                    new ValidationContext(this, null, null) { MemberName = "OrgZipValue" });
                _zip = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("OrgZipValue");
            }
        }
    }

    public string OrgCountyValue
    {
        get { return _county; }
        set
        {
            if (_county != value)
            {
                Validator.ValidateProperty(value,
                    new ValidationContext(this, null, null) { MemberName = "OrgCountyValue" });
                _county = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("OrgCountyValue");
            }
        }
    }

    public string OrgServiceAreaValue
    {
        get { return _serviceArea; }
        set
        {
            if (_serviceArea != value)
            {
                Validator.ValidateProperty(value,
                    new ValidationContext(this, null, null) { MemberName = "OrgServiceAreaValue" });
                _serviceArea = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("OrgServiceAreaValue");
            }
        }
    }

    public bool CBO
    {
        get { return _cbo; }
        set
        {
            _cbo = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CBO");
        }
    }

    public bool FBO
    {
        get { return _fbo; }
        set
        {
            _fbo = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FBO");
        }
    }

    public bool SBO
    {
        get { return _sbo; }
        set
        {
            _sbo = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SBO");
        }
    }

    public bool MO
    {
        get { return _mo; }
        set
        {
            _mo = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MO");
        }
    }

    public bool SNO
    {
        get { return _sno; }
        set
        {
            _sno = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SNO");
        }
    }
}
```

**EventDetailsTab:**

```
<TabItem Header="Event Details" x:Name="EventDetailsTab"
            Style="{StaticResource TabStyle}"
            DataContext="{Binding EventDetails}">
    <eventTabs:_1_EventDetailsTab />
</TabItem>
```

**OrganizationDetailsTab:**

```
<TabItem Header="Organization" x:Name="OrganizationTab"
            Style="{StaticResource TabStyle}"
            DataContext="{Binding OrganizationDetails}">
    <eventTabs:_2_OrganizationTab />
</TabItem>
```

As I said the bindings work flawlessly overall, but I want to reference a binding associated with OrganizationDetails for a control that resides in both the EventDetailsTab and OrganizationDetailsTab.

The code for that item is as follows...

```
<ComboBox Name="OrgNameComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding OrganizationSource}"
                SelectedValue="{Binding OrganizationSelected,
                                        Mode=TwoWay,
                                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Comment: Do you want something like this: When you select `OrganizationA` in the `Combobox`, both `OrganizationDetailsTab` and `EventDetailsTab` changed base the selected item (`OrganizationA`) OR have 2 combobox in 2 tab with *fully separated* behaviors after you select one of its items???

Comment: @RAM that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the DataContext for your event details tab to `{Binding EventDetails}` and the DataContext for your organization tab to `{Binding OrganizationDetails}`, but the `OrganizationSource` and `OrganizationSelected` fields that your ComboBoxes are binding to only exist in the OrganizationDetailsVMB class. A quick hack would be to change your event details ComboBox to point to the correct place with a RelativeSource binding back to the TabItem's DataContext and down again to the OrganizationDetails:

```
<ComboBox Name="OrgNameComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding OrganizationSource}"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabControl}, Path=DataContext.OrganizationDetails}" 
        SelectedValue="{Binding OrganizationSelected,
        Mode=TwoWay,
        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

To be perfectly honest though I think you need to clean up your architecture. Your view model appears very tightly coupled to your underlying data model instead of the view, to the point where you're even accessing your table adapters in your getters which means A) you have no way of doing session management, B) your view performance will now be throttled by your DAL and you'll start having performance issues, and C) trying to introduce any type of multi-threading will cause all manner of access conflicts in your ORM.

Comment: I am fairly new to this MVVM concept. I was trying to find a way to have one main VM and have the separate View Model Bases that can be included in the main view model. The reason is to make the code cleaner to look at.

Answer (score 0):

### A)

This way is good when you want have some data (like a combobox info) across an `App` or `Multi Window`:

Create 3 `ViewModel` (all inherited from `INotifyPropertyChanged`).

1. **`OrganizationViewModel`**:  *INCLUDE* **`OrganizationSource`** and **`OrganizationSelected`**
2. **`OrganizationDetailsViewModel`**: *WHITHOUT* **`OrganizationSource`** and **`OrganizationSelected`**
3. **`OrganizationEventsViewModel`**: *WHITHOUT* **`OrganizationSource`** and **`OrganizationSelected`**

Now you can create a simple `Static` class named `GeneralData` & make a `static` property in it of `OrganizationViewModel` type like this:

```
public static class GeneralData{
   public static OrganizationViewModel Organization {get;set;}
}
```

In the `App.xaml.cs` fill the `Organization` property of the `GeneralData` class with a new instance of `OrganizationViewModel`.

---

Ok... Now we have every things we need to start playing....

Every time you want to fill the `ComboBox` you should use the `Organization` [static property] of `GeneralData` class like this:

```
<ComboBox Name="OrgNameComboBox"
          DataSource="{Binding Source={x:Static GeneralData.Organization}}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static GeneralData.Organization.OrganizationSource}}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding Source={x:Static GeneralData.Organization.OrganizationSelected,
                                  Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

And every time you want check which item of the Combobox is selected in code-behind (such as inside the `ViewModels`) you can easily check it like this:

```
var selectedOrganisation = GeneralData.Organization.OrganizationSelected;
```

Note: i recommend to you before closing the window that include the ComboBox run this code (to make sure there is not any alive reference to the static property):

```
BindingOperations.ClearAllBindings(OrgNameComboBox);
```

---

### **B)**

If you have just 1 window include 2 UserControl then prevent `static` properties and instead of above way use this way:

Create 3 `ViewModel` (all inherited from `INotifyPropertyChanged`).

1. **`OrganizationViewModel`**:  *INCLUDE* **`OrganizationSource`** and **`OrganizationSelected`**
2. **`OrganizationDetailsViewModel`**: *WHITHOUT* **`OrganizationSource`** and **`OrganizationSelected`**
3. **`OrganizationEventsViewModel`**: *WHITHOUT* **`OrganizationSource`** and **`OrganizationSelected`**

Now easily implement this scenario:

In `Window1.xaml.cs`:

```
Window1.DataSource= new OrganizationViewModel();
```

In `EventUserControl.xaml.cs`:

```
EventUserControl.DataSource= new OrganizationEventsViewModel();
```

In `OrganizationDetailsUserControl.xaml.cs`:

```
EventUserControl.DataSource= new OrganizationDetailsViewModel();
```

Now create a `DependencyProperty` in both `EventUserControl` and `OrganizationDetailsUserControl` to give them  the `SelectedItem` of `ComboBox`. Your property type should be `string`. you can create the `DependencyProperty`s base on [this tutorial](http://wpftutorial.net/DependencyProperties.html).
For example use this name for your `DependencyProperty`s in both `UserControl`s: **`SelectedOrganisation`**

OK, put the `Combobox` in the `Window1.xaml` (NOT inside any `UserControl`).
Now we fill these `SelectedOrganisation`s from outer their `UserControls` like the following codes.

In `Window1.xaml`

```
<uc.OrganizationDetailsUserControl 
    SelectedOrganisation="{Binding ElementName=OrgNameComboBox, Path=SelectedItem}"/>

<uc.EventUserControl
    SelectedOrganisation="{Binding ElementName=OrgNameComboBox, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
```

Now you have the `SelectedItem` of the `ComboBox` inside your `UserControl` you can play with it inside the `UserControls` and call some methods of the `ViewModels` with `SelectedOrganisation` as method parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The route I took is the [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://www.mvvmlight.net/).